# run .net core application in development from the command line

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I know I can configure some settings in Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code to launch my asp .net core application in development mode. But I've had a horrible experience with all the build tools, and so far running from the command line is the only one working for me.

The big problem I have with the command line is getting it to run in Development mode. If I understand, this can only be done by typing `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` before `dotnet watch run` or by setting system wide environment variables. There's gotta be another way, like through a file or something.

How can I run in Development mode from the command line, so I can include this in say a `package.json` of an Aurelia project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `--environment` argument with `dotnet run` to specify hosting environment:

```
 dotnet run --environment "Development"
```

But this will work only after you modify host building to use configuration with command line arguments as config source.

- add dependency to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine` package
- add to  `main` method the config creation based on arguments by adding `AddCommandLine` extension method for `ConfigurationBuilder` :

  ```
  var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()  
     .AddCommandLine(args)
     .Build();
  ```
- use configuration by adding `.UseConfiguration(config)` step during host setup.

  ```
  var host = new WebHostBuilder()  
     .UseConfiguration(config)
     .UseKestrel()
     .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .UseIISIntegration()
     .UseStartup<Startup>()
     .Build();
  ```

Comment: thansk for the response, i like the solution, but i can't get it to work. i added the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine reference: "
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="1.1.1" />" but AddCommandLine is not a valid method. Any ideas?

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis don't forget to do package restore and add `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;`